# Filtering Data using RDD from CSV file

Tags: csv, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark and trying a way to figure out how can I use filter in RDD with multiple conditions and get the count of the records.Scenario is as below:

- There is one CSV file which has multiple column header like ID,Date,Description,Type,Year etc.

If I want to find out how many records are there for YEAR=2018 and TYPE=comedy.

I don't need solution using DataSet/DataFrame but only using RDD with map and filter.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have tried so far.

Comment: What is the type of your RDD, Row or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this  :

```
input=sc.textFile("<<path>>");



input_filtered=input.filter(lambda row : return (row.split(",")[3]=="comedy" and row.split(",")[5]=="2018")  )


input_filetered.count()
```

Another option would be to use foreach with an accumulator.Hope it helps.

Comment: I think it is easier to use Spark's built in csv support.

Comment: Yes . Its true . but he is expecting RDD instant of DataSet. If we use spark built in csv will return DataSet<Row> and hecan manupulate on that instant of converting to RDD and doing manipulation . I think he is working on some older code @TerryDactyl .

Comment: Yes,What I was looking is the older way of transformation and filter using only core RDDs.I tried something similar to what @Kuldip Puri Tejaswi proposed.But the count was coming zero.I'll try again and update.

Comment: It will work...assuming the column order stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have RDD[Row] and each column is of StringType then

```
myRdd.filter(r => r.getAs("YEAR") == "2018" && r.getAs("TYPE") == "COMEDY")
```

It really depends how you have read your data.

Here is how you can read the file as an RDD[Row].

```
val myRdd = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").load("myFile.csv").rdd
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your expecting like below.

```
JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("readcsvyear.csv");
            JavaRDD<String> filtered = lines.filter(line -> {
                String[] list = line.split(",");
                if(list.length >= 5 && list[4].equalsIgnoreCase("2018")) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
            System.out.println(filtered);

            for(String line:filtered.collect()){
                System.out.println("filtered "+line);
            }
```

Input file

```
1,Date,desc,type,2018
2,Date,desc,type,2018
3,Date,desc,type,2018
4,Date,desc,type,2018
5,Date,desc,type,2018
6,Date,desc,type,2017
7,Date,desc,type,2017
8,Date,desc,type,2017
```

Output

```
filtered 1,Date,desc,type,2018
filtered 2,Date,desc,type,2018
filtered 3,Date,desc,type,2018
filtered 4,Date,desc,type,2018
filtered 5,Date,desc,type,2018
```